# How do I support Call Mute (Universal Mute) in my app for Windows 11 22H2?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-11

Windows 22H2 introduces a new hotkey (`Win+Alt+K` [See [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) under "Windows Logo Key shortucts"]) to mute calls. It corresponds to this UI in taskbar:

[image: Microphone usage button in taskbar]

It works when I use Teams, but not when I use Mumble:

[image: No supported apps in use for mic mute]

The shortcuts guide indicates that it's available in Windows 11 22H2 for apps that support "Call Mute":

> Toggle microphone mute in apps that support Call Mute. Available starting in Windows 11, version 22H2.

**What APIs do I need to consume in order to support this new hotkey?**

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: Tentatively, the `VoipPhoneCall` and `VoipCallCoordinator` APIs are the way to go (see [`VoipCallCoordinator.RequestNewOngoingCall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.voipcallcoordinator.requestnewoutgoingcall?view=winrt-22621), the `MuteStateChanged` event, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 steps needed to support the Universal Mute button in your own apps:

1. Create a new `VoipPhoneCall` with the [`VoipCallCoordinator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.voipcallcoordinator?view=winrt-22621).
2. Handle the [`VoipCallCoordinator.MuteStateChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.voipcallcoordinator.mutestatechanged?view=winrt-22621) and fire the appropriate `NotifyMuted` or `NotifyUnmuted` function when your app has muted/unmuted in response.

For example:

```cs
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;

var coordinator = VoipCallCoordinator.GetDefault();
coordinator.MuteStateChanged += (e, args) => {
    Console.WriteLine($"Mute changed! - {args.Muted}");

    // Respond that the app has muted/unmuted.
    if (args.Muted) {
        coordinator.NotifyMuted();
    } else {
        coordinator.NotifyUnmuted();
    }
};

// No change until you press enter here:
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to 'start' a call. Ctrl-C to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();

var call = coordinator.RequestNewOutgoingCall("context_link_todo", "Satya Nadella", "DummyPhone", VoipPhoneCallMedia.Audio);
call.NotifyCallActive();

// Win-Alt-K will display your app muted/unmuted until you press enter:
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to 'end' the call.");
Console.ReadLine();
call.NotifyCallEnded();
```

See https://github.com/citelao/Universal-Mute for a full C# demo and https://github.com/citelao/mumble-universal-mute/releases/tag/v0.0.1 for a plugin that makes this work for Mumble.

[image: Mic unmuted (DummyPhone) popup]

Comment: That's real neat, now can you please send this info to the folks making Edge so they can expose it on the web?